# Why "could not extract resultset" error occurs?

Tags: hibernate

I want to get the record from database by id. Below you can see my query:

```
public StudentEntity getStudentById(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from StudentEntity where idstudent = :id").setParameter("id", id);

    StudentEntity studentEntity = (StudentEntity) query.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    return studentEntity;
}
```

My StudentEntity class you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/abayKenzhekhan/55ca3a1cbd931654cb55b706eb0e027a)

My stack trace you can see [here](https://gist.github.com/abayKenzhekhan/7cc94b83c038525d338ca7ff0029a09b)
With other tables I don't get such error. That's why I suppose that the mistake is in StudentEntity class. What can be reason for this error? How can I solve it? Github page of project [here](https://github.com/abayKenzhekhan/the_dl_app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: What can be reason for this error?

A: The stack trace reveals that MySQL is returning error 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 
'as docExpir4_3_, studentent0_.docIssueOrgnazation as docIssue5_3_, studentent0_.'
at line 1
```

This means that Hibernate has attempted to prepare or execute a SQL statement that MySQL doesn't understand. There's a syntax error of some kind. We're going to rule out the use of a reserved word as a column name, as Hibernate should be qualifying column references in SELECT statements. And I think we can rule out an invalid column reference, because MySQL would return a different error (1054) for that condition.

Q: How can I solve it?

A: Capture the SQL being executed.

Enable either DEBUG or TRACE for Hibernate, so it logs the SQL statements it is executing...  in the log4j configuration, either

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

---

There really is no substitute for learning *how to debug* programs that you write.

---

With that said, MySQL column names that include a space need to be properly escaped. For example, if we execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT foo.fee fi AS fo FROM fum foo
```

MySQL server throws a 1064 syntax error "`near  'AS fo '`"

We don't get that syntax error if we enclose the column name in backtick characters.

```
SELECT foo.`fee fi` AS fo FROM fum foo
           ^      ^
```

With Hibernate native API, we can get the column name enclosed in single backticks.

```
@Column(name = "`fee fi`")
```

Using JPA, we can enclose in double quotes

```
@Column(name = "\"fee fi\"")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The reason from the stack trace

```
'as docExpir4_3_, studentent0_.docIssueOrgnazation as docIssue5_3_, studentent0_.'
```

One of the columns doesn't have a name `studentent0_.`. Please, check `StudentEntity` class.

At least this is incorrect

```
@Column(name = "Payment type", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getPaymentType() {
    return paymentType;
}

@Column(name = "docExpire time", nullable = true)
public Date getDocExpireTime() {
    return docExpireTime;
}
```